# Install libsvn With SSL Support on Ubuntu (9.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, svn, git

The `subversion` package which is available from the Ubuntu 9.04 repositories has a very annoying limitation which make it basically unusable for repositories hosted on `https://`.  The accepted solution to this problem is to compile subversion by hand from the sources hosted at Tigris, being sure to configure using the `--with-ssl` option.

This works fine for the `svn` CLI client, but it breaks down with respect to other tools which use libsvn.  I'm assuming that the hand compilation bit does install the corrected libsvn `.so`(s), but they are not used by packages like `git-svn` which are installed via APT.

So, here's the question: how do I get `git-svn` working on Ubuntu with repositories hosted on `https://`?

Answer (score 1):

Until this is fixed in the ubuntu repositories, you are probably better off compiling git and git-svn yourself as well. Just make sure when you compile git-svn that you point it to the right libraries in the configure.

I even tried upgrading to the karmic packages for libsvn1, libsvn-perl, subversion, git-core and git-svn with all their dependencies and still no luck.

```
git-svn:
  Installed: 1:1.6.3.3-2
git-core:
  Installed: 1:1.6.3.3-2
libsvn1:
  Installed: 1.6.1dfsg-1ubuntu2
subversion:
  Installed: 1.6.1dfsg-1ubuntu2
libsvn-perl:
  Installed: 1.6.1dfsg-1ubuntu2
```

Seems to be related to [this ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/+bug/43423). Also thanks for diagnosing this, it's a problem I was about to learn I had.